# Simple Bluetooth device monitor with timestamps

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, timestamp, bluez

I have a Raspberry Pi whatever (yes, with BT) and I'd like it to function as a very simple Bluetooth monitor which records beacons/nearby-device-ids/whatevers that it hears about in a big long text file for later processing.

I have `bluez` et al. installed, and I can even do a

```
sudo bluetoothctl -- scan on
```

to get a nice ANSI-colored output of devices nearby:

```
[NEW] Device A3:33:00:AB:CC:FF A3-33-00-AB-CC-FF
[CHG] Device A3:33:00:AB:CC:FF RSSI: -72
```

&c

I can capture this output to a text file using the shell, and, despite the ANSI control character stuff, I'm very very happy.

The only thing I want but don't have is a timestamp against each entry.

OMG I've tried ***everything***. I don't even ***care*** about sub-second precision. *Pleeeeeease* just some timestamps. I will just ***die*** if I can't get them.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't ***die***.

As I tested this prepend timestamps:

```
bluetoothctl | tr -d '\r' | while read -r line; do echo "$(date +%T) $line"; done
```

Using this method we can track how many seconds ago bluetooth tags with MAC starting with `AA:BB:CC:DD` were seen:

```
bluetoothctl | awk '/Device AA:BB:CC:DD/' | tr -d '\r' | while read -r line; do 

    MAC=_$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f4 | tr -d ':')
    
    declare ${MAC}_TS=$(date +%s)
    
    TMP=${MAC}_TS
    TS=${!TMP}

    TMP=${MAC}_PREV_TS
    PREV_TS=${!TMP}

    printf "%-2d %s\n" "$((TS - PREV_TS))" "$line"

    declare ${MAC}_PREV_TS=$TS

done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command:

```
stdbuf -oL bluetoothctl -- scan on | ts
```

Explanation:

The `ts` utility adds a timestamp to the beginning of each line of input. It has many useful options like timestamp format, absolute or relative times (either elapsed time since the start of `ts` or since the previous line).

However, most programs, including bluetoothctl buffer their output if it is not connected to a terminal. This means that if we pipe the output into `ts`, nothing will get displayed until the buffer gets full, which means that a *lot* of lines have to accumulate before they all get flushed *at once*, defeating the purpose of `ts`. To work around this, we can use the `stdbuf` utility to override output buffering to happen line by line, i.e. as soon as a line is output it gets flushed and ts can timestamp and display it.